# How to Make Laravel Eloquent "AND" in a Query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am making a website in my job and I have an issue.

This is what I want to do; in `MySQL` (`PHPMyAdmin`) it works with no problems:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tipo_usuarios
INNER JOIN users
    ON tipo_usuarios.id = users.id AND 
       tipo_usuarios.jerarquia = "Administrador";
```

[image: PHPMyAdmin successful query run]

Well this is my Eloquent in Laravel, it works but only with IDs. I don't know how to add `AND` in Eloquent.

```php
$visitas = User::join("visitas", "visitas.id_usuario", "=", "users.id")
    ->select("*")
    ->get();
```

[image: code]

Comment: use advanced join https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#advanced-join-clauses so inside the closure add the `on` method + the `where` method. Also, the query could be done easily if you have the relation `tipo_usuarios` declared.

Comment: Hi man, thanks it works     $empleados = DB::table('users')
            ->join('tipo_consumidores', 'users.id', '=', 'tipo_consumidores.id')
            ->select('users.*')
            ->where('tipo_consumidores.tipo', '=', "Empleado")
            ->get();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function for second argument in join

```
$visitas = User::join("visitas", function ($join) {
    $join->on("visitas.id_usuario", "=", "users.id")
        ->on("visitas.jerarquia","=","Administrador")
})
    ->select("*")
    ->get();
```

However, you should read the documentation for creating Eloquent relationship. This is a more convenient and understandable functionality than using the query builder

[Eloquent relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Hi friends, thank you for your help It works look :   $empleados = DB::table('users')
            ->join('tipo_consumidores', 'users.id', '=', 'tipo_consumidores.id')
            ->select('users.*')
            ->where('tipo_consumidores.tipo', '=', "Empleado")
            ->get();

Comment: right!  this is also a solution.  however, try to start using eloquent relationships.